# FreeRTOS: Assigning One Task Handler To Two Tasks

Tags: freertos, rtos

I'm new to FreeRTOS and was playing around with task creation basics and found out the following:

*If two tasks' control blocks are assigned to the same task handler, then the task that was created last gets total control over this task handler*

I created two tasks to increment/decrement a shared resource signed integer. I did it two ways, first like this for the task handler:

```
//shared variable to increment/decrement
int x = 0;

void myTask_increment_decrement(void *pvParameters)
{
    while(1) {
        bool *paramThatDeterminesIncrementOrDecrement = (bool *)(pvParameters);
        if(*paramThatDeterminesIncrementOrDecrement) {
            x = x + 1;
        }
        else {
            x = x - 1;
        }
    }
}

Thread Creation:

  BaseType_t status1 = xTaskCreate(
          myTask_increment_decrement,
          "myTaskIncrement",
          configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE,
          (void *)true,
          2,
          &g_taskHandle1);

  BaseType_t status2 = xTaskCreate(
          myTask_increment_decrement,
          "myTaskDecrement",
          configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE,
          (void *)false,
          2,
          &g_taskHandle2);
```

I found that only the decrementation task is called and x is never incremented. When I broke my singular task handler into two separate task handlers, one for incrementation, and one for decrementation, both incrementation and decrementation occurred for the shared resource

Why is it not viable to get two possible behaviors from two tasks both bound to the same task handler?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't working because you are directly passing the values `true` and `false` when creating the tasks, instead of pointers to variables with a true/false value, and then treating those values as pointers.

You should create the tasks like this instead:

```c
bool true_variable = true;
bool false_variable = false;

BaseType_t status1 = xTaskCreate(
          myTask_increment_decrement,
          "myTaskIncrement",
          configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE,
          (void *) &true_variable,
          2,
          &g_taskHandle1);

BaseType_t status2 = xTaskCreate(
          myTask_increment_decrement,
          "myTaskDecrement",
          configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE,
          (void *) &false_variable,
          2,
          &g_taskHandle2);
```

Alternatively, you can directly pass a number but you shouldn't treat it as a pointer because it isn't a valid address. This is what [the example in the official documentation](https://www.freertos.org/a00125.html) does.

```c
int x = 0;

void myTask_increment_decrement(void *pvParameters)
{
    while(1) {
        int paramThatDeterminesIncrementOrDecrement = (int)(pvParameters);
        if(paramThatDeterminesIncrementOrDecrement == 1) {
            x = x + 1;
        }
        else {
            x = x - 1;
        }
    }
}

BaseType_t status1 = xTaskCreate(
          myTask_increment_decrement,
          "myTaskIncrement",
          configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE,
          (void *) 1,
          2,
          &g_taskHandle1);

BaseType_t status2 = xTaskCreate(
          myTask_increment_decrement,
          "myTaskDecrement",
          configMINIMAL_STACK_SIZE,
          (void *) 0,
          2,
          &g_taskHandle2);
```